# Cuando android libera memoria, al reiniciar mi aplicación se detiene

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para android, la aplicación funciona correctamente, lo que sucede es que al dejarla en segundo plano, cuando android libera memoria, y yo intento reiniciarla aplicación, se detiene.

He estado leyendo e implemente AppCenter, el error al parecer son valores nulos.

Como puedo resolver esto?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Comment: "y yo intento reiniciarla aplicación," intenta reiniciarla o regresar de segundo plano? Explica lo que realiza tu aplicación , agrega el código, agrega lo que indica el LogCat o la consola.

Comment: intento abrir la aplicación desde el segundo plano de android, el LogCat o consola no me arroja ningún resultado, porque cuando intento abrirla no alcanza a ejecutar nada. Lo único que tengo es el AppCenter, el me arroja que hay un NullReferenceException en el OnCreate en la actividad en la que deje la aplicación cuando la deje en segundo plano.